# Nested calculation of sum with Sqlite query

Tags: php, sql, sqlite

### I have

a Sqlite Database with the following Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE User (
  ID_User integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  Name text
);

CREATE TABLE Payment (
  ID_Payment integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  ID_Advancer integer,
  Amount integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  Title text,
  Datetxt text
);

CREATE TABLE PayersUser (
  ID_User integer,
  ID_Payment integer
);
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/931dc2/1

Meaning of the Schema:

- A User kann make a payment (entries `Payment.ID_Advancer`, `Payment.ID_Advancer`) henceforth called asset.
- This asset is divided between zero or more Users (entries `PayersUser.ID_User`,`PayersUser.ID_Payment`) henceforth called stake.
- The debt of a User is the sum of his stakes.
- The sum for a User is the sum of his asset - his debt.

### I want

to select the resulting sum of Payments Users did.

```
SELECT <...> AS `sum`, `User`.`Name` FROM <...>;

| sum | User.Name |;
|=====|===========|;
|18.33| A         |;
|23.33| B         |;
|-11.6| C         |;
```

Exemplary procedure:

1. Get a List of `User.ID_User` with `User.name` from Table User.
2. For every `User.ID_User` in that List I do the following:

   1. calculate the `assetsOfAUser` by
      `SELECT SUM(Payment.Amount) as assetsOfAUser WHERE Payment.ID_Advancer == User.ID_User;`
   2. calculate the `debtsOfAUser` by

      1. get a List`SELECT Payment.ID_Payment WHERE Payment.ID_Advancer == User.ID_User` without dublicates
      2. for every `Payment.ID_Payment as myPaymentID` in that List do:

         1. get the corresponding `Payment.Amount as`myPaymentAmount`
         2. get the count of `PayerUser.ID_User as countOfPayers` where `Payment.ID_Payment = myPaymentID`
         3. calculate `stakeOfAUser = (PaymentAmount/countOfPayers)`
      3. calculate `debtsOfAUser = SUM( stakeOfAUser )`
   3. calculate `sumOfAUser = (assetsOfAUser - debtsOfAUser)`
3. return a List `sumOfAUser as sum, User.name`

### Example

```
INSERT INTO User (`Name`) VALUES ('A');
INSERT INTO User (`Name`) VALUES ('B');
INSERT INTO User (`Name`) VALUES ('C');
INSERT INTO User (`Name`) VALUES ('D');
INSERT INTO User (`Name`) VALUES ('F');

INSERT INTO Payment (`ID_Advancer`,`Amount`,`Title`)
  VALUES ('1', '20', 'Test1');
INSERT INTO Payment (`ID_Advancer`,`Amount`,`Title`)
  VALUES ('1', '5', 'Test2');
INSERT INTO Payment (`ID_Advancer`,`Amount`,`Title`)
  VALUES ('2', '30', 'Test3');

INSERT INTO PayersUser (`ID_User`,`ID_Payment`) VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO PayersUser (`ID_User`,`ID_Payment`) VALUES (2, 1);
INSERT INTO PayersUser (`ID_User`,`ID_Payment`) VALUES (3, 1);
INSERT INTO PayersUser (`ID_User`,`ID_Payment`) VALUES (3, 2);
```

Should Result in:

```
| sum               | User.Name |;
|===================|===========|;
| +20+5-(20/3)      | A         |;
|    30-(20/3)      | B         |;
|     0-(20/3)-(5/1)| C         |;
```

- User `A` made a Payment of 20 and 5: [+5][+20]
- User `A` is one of three Users that the Payment "Test1" of 20 is divided between: [-(20/3)]
- User `B` made a Payment of 30: [+30]
- User `B` is one of three Users that the Payment "Test1" of 20 is divided between: [-(20/3)]
- User `C` made no Payment: [+0]
- User `C` is one of three Users that the Payment "Test1" of 20 is divided between: [-(20/3)]
- User `C` is the only User (one of one) that the Payment "Test2" of 5 is divided between: [-(5/1)]

### I tried

Inner Joins and inline views in the sqlite requests.
Also loading parts of Data and calculate the sum in php.
But no matter what, it always got to complex and incomprehensible for me to get a result.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/931dc2/1

---

I am Using php PDO. A solution with more Logic in php would be also ok.
My Priorities are

1. It is Working
2. Easy to understand and maintainable

Comment: Post the SQL here, not just at sqlfiddle.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by `Payment.Amount divided between PayersUser.ID_User`

Comment: Where does the `3` in `20/3` come from? Is it because there are `3` rows in `PayersUser` with `ID_Payment = 1`?

Comment: Your explanation of how the results are calculated doens't mention `ID_Payment` at all.

Comment: Do you mean "steak" or "stake"?

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I edited my question and added more detailed explanations. Hopefully it helps understanding my issue.